# Is there any other way to access the n-th element of a BlankSequence x__?

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider a named `BlankSequence` `x__`. How can I access the n-th element?
Is `{x}[[n]]` the only way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) (that is, `#n & @ x`):

```
Cases[{x__, 1} :> ( #4 & @ x)][
  {{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w,  1}, {a, b, c, 1}}]
```

[image]

and [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) (that is, `Indexed[{x}, n]`):

```
Cases[{x__, 1} :> Indexed[{x}, 4]][
  {{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w, 1}, {a, b, c, 1}}]
```

[image]

compare with `Part`:

```
Cases[{x__, 1} :> {x}[[4]]][
  {{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w, 1}, {a, b, c, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Repeated` instead of `BlankSequence` to match the fourth element directly. Using the example from kglr:

```
Cases[{Repeated[_, {3}], x_, ___, 1} :> x][
  {{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w,  1}, {a, b, c, 1}}]
```

> {d, w}

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this sort of result?

```
{{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w, 1}, 
 {a, b, c, 1}} /. {x__, 1} :> Last[{x}]

(* Out: {{a, 2}, e, w, c} *)
```

Or:

```
{{a, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}, {x, y, z, w, 1},
  {a, b, c, 1}} /. {x__, 1} :> Take[{x}, {Length[{x} - 1]}]

(* Out: {{a, 2}, {e}, {w}, {c}} *)
```